# In TypoScript, how to check for a setting on parent page

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

In TypoScript, you can check for a setting in page details:

```
if.isTrue.data = page:tx_myext_siblingsnav
```

In my case, to display a submenu.

But now I would like to check if this setting exists on the parent page (no "slide").

```
if.isTrue.data = levelfield:-2,page:tx_myext_siblingsnav
```

Wouldn't work.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if.isTrue.data = levelfield:-2,tx_myext_siblingsnav
```

and in AdditionalConfiguration.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['addRootLineFields'] = 'tx_myext_siblingsnav';
```

(I thought the rootlinefields had to be added only for "slide", but no.)